# SQLite database won't use WHERE properly?

Tags: java

The purpose of this app is to get workouts from a database based on what the user selects, and put them into a textview in a fragmented class. The user can select their experience and if they want to use weights. The database stores all the workouts associated with the experience and weights. For example, in my database I may have a workout that has ( "beginner","no weights", "inclined pushups"). At the end of the app, the database should researched for values that the user selected. For example, it should only find database entries that have beginner if that's what the user choice. I want the database to only return the workout. I am using Android Studio for this, and created the database (as well as populated it), but I keep getting the same error. The first method below is in another class that should get the workout by experience and weight preference in the database.

```
    public ArrayList<String> getWorkoutByBeginnerAndNoWeights(){

        Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXERCISES, workoutColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EXPERIENCE + "=" + "beginner" + "AND" + "" + MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_EQUIPMENT + "=" + "no weights", null, null, null, null);
        while(!cursor.isLast()){
            int i=0;
            String workouts =cursor.getString(i++);
            workoutArray.add(workouts);

        }

        //return string array
        return workoutArray;
    }


----------
Class for making the database

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_EXERCISES = "exercises";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_EXPERIENCE = "experience";
    public static final String COLUMN_EQUIPMENT = "equipment";
    public static final String COLUMN_WORKOUT = "workout";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exercises.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_EXERCISES + "(" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "+ COLUMN_EXPERIENCE + " text not null,  " + COLUMN_EQUIPMENT
            + " text not null, "+ COLUMN_WORKOUT
            + " text not null);";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EXERCISES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


-------
Code in fragment to display it as a text using textView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) inf.findViewById(R.id.testText);
        tv.setText(MainActivity.dataSource.getWorkoutByBeginnerAndNoWeights().toString());
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inf;
    }


----------
error I am getting
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hfad.workoutmaker, PID: 20245
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: beginner (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, workout FROM exercises WHERE experience=beginner
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1165)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1204)
        at com.hfad.workoutmaker.WorkoutsDataSource.getWorkoutByBeginnerAndNoWeights(WorkoutsDataSource.java:74)
        at com.hfad.workoutmaker.TestFragment.onCreateView(TestFragment.java:41)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `'beginner'` not `beginner` as your value.

So a simple SQL statement should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `ID`='1'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, unfortunately, the problem is giving the same errors even with `` around the values and equal signs. I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: Your problem is, that sql thinks that your value us a column:   `column: beginner`
Try to break down your problem. Don't use multible final variables for debugging, just use one String for your sql statement. Only use one condition for WHERE like `"experience='beginner'"`. Use phpmyadmin or something else to test your SQL statements. And so on... (default debugging procedure)